# Parse trailing line comments with lark and LALR

Tags: python, parsing, lalr, lark-parser

Given are the following [lark](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/grammar/) grammar and Python source code:

```
start: (TEXT _NEWLINE)+

TEXT: /[^\n]+/

COMMENT: /\/\/[^\n]*/ _NEWLINE
%ignore COMMENT

_NEWLINE: (" "* "\n")+
```

```py
from lark import Lark

parser = Lark.open("grammar.lark", parser='lalr')

parser.parse("""Lorem ipsum
// line comment
Text with // trailing comment
""")
```

The above parser produces this tree:
[image: actual tree]

The first line of text is parsed correctly and the second line (which is a comment) is ignored as was intended. However, the last line contains the comment that is supposed to be ignored.

This is the expected output:
[image: expected tree]

I realize that it is perfectly legal in my grammar to have two consecutive slashes in a `TEXT` node (which should actually introduce a line comment). However, I do not know how to prevent this. Is there any way I can disallow two consecutive slashes in `TEXT` or give higher priority to the `COMMENT` terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a grammar that seems to work:

```
start: (TEXT _NEWLINE)+

TEXT: /(\/?[^\n\/])+/

COMMENT: /\/\/[^\n]*/
%ignore COMMENT

_NEWLINE: (" "* COMMENT? "\n")+
```

*I doubt this is the most elegant solution, so I'd appreciate another answer or suggestions.*